# How can I cancel a subscription item in Stripe at end of billing period

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe API and Laravel 5.4

My business logic requires that a user have 1 `subscription` and if the user needs to add more functionality they will be added as `subscription items` to that main `subscription`.

Now if a user were to cancel one of the services(functionality) he requested he needs to be able to use that functionality for the remainder of the current billing period and should only be billed for the time used.

In the API documentation I see that I can achieve this with a `subscription` by setting `cancel_at_period_end = true` but can't seem to find the equivalent when dealing with just a `subscription item` within a `subscription`.

Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A `subscription_item` (as well as a `plan`) doesn't currently support deleting it automatically at the end of the billing period.

A workaround for this:

1. For the current `subscription`, set the subscription to `cancel_at_period_end = true`.
2. Create a new `subscription` with all the same `subscription_items` as the original `subscription` (except for the item that they're cancelling), but set it to be a free trial until the same time as the current `subscription`.

Using that method, the customer can keep using all of their functionality until the end of the billing period. The "new" subscription won't be charged at all during the overlap time. At the end of the current billing period, the old subscription will end and the new subscription will begin.

Comment: Thanks @taintedzodiac. Is there an automated way of doing this or do I have to do this manually at the end of a billing period?

Comment: @natral It can really be done at any point during the current billing cycle. As long as the "free trial" of the new subscription ends at the same time that the old subscription's billing cycle ends, there won't be any interruption in service.

Comment: @natral what about using items[0].deleted = true for the respective subscription item?

Answer (score 3):

You can **update** the subscription to expire at the end of the billing period, as explained in [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update).

```js
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(
  'sub_IlS7kzn3wPGV9D',
  {cancel_at_period_end: true}
);
```

Comment: He can already do it for the subscription. What he wants is for subscription item.